# Binding TextBox to insert data with entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-4

I want to insert data from a form Data Base (used with entity Framwork), until the day I used the manual way as below.

```
var member = new MorEntities();
Person one_person = new Person
{
   First_Name=txt_F_N.Text,
   Family_Name = txt_L_N.Text,
}
member.People.AddObject(one_person);
member.SaveChanges();
```

To the best understood in WPF, there is a way in the XAML (binding),
 I checked online and could not understand,
 can anyone give a small example from which I will continue

Answer (score 1):

You can uses so called Properties with public getters and setters and bind that to the textbox

```
public class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Person = new Person();
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveExecuted);
    }

    // Properties
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    // Commands
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    private void SaveExecuted()
    {
        // Do some save logic here!
    }

}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And in your textbox XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}" />
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save"/>
```

And in the codebehind add this line

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new MainViewModel(); //Add this line
}
```

something like that
dont forget to set the DataContext of the View to itself or another public object you want to use the properties of.

also take a look at [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) nice way to use WPF and use separation of conserns

Make a button on you View called Save and Band this button to a  [Command](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM) like you do with the other properties
And in the Execute method save to the Database or update.

the NotificationObject and DelegateCommand are from [Prism 4](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why does it seem the simplest way better than mine (it's more complicated)

Comment: Well I'm not saying this is the simplest way, your not asking for the simplest way. You were looking for a small sample from which you could start. I think this is a nice way to start. And if you don't understand just ask.

Comment: First thanks for the reply and the help ,To this day I have not touched in MVVM, where to start? What to download?

Comment: If you click on the link [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) of my first post you can see some information about MVVM. You don't have to install anything to use MVVM, there are however a couple of libs that will help you using it. Like [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) but a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to have one-way and two-way bindings is enough.

Comment: I still think this is the answer to your question maybe you can accept it answer